# Docusign api integration with asp.net mvc form to capture the signature

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docusignapi, integrate

I have web application with the form built in asp.net. At the end of the form i have to capture the signature of the users using docusign. I dont want to create any form in the docusign. Everything shouldbe handled by me on the form and i have to save the signature in the database with other fields of the form. 
Please let me know if its possible with docusing api.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow`, please be a bit more specific when asking question: *What have you tried so far with code example?* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"*

Comment: save signature means, you do not want to save complete document?

Comment: I want to save document on our web portal. Also, save password separately

Comment: The whole point of using a service like docusign is you don't really need to do that. You can just store a link to the document instead. Then there is one verifiable, up-to-date copy, instead of multiple ones which you then have to keep in sync. But they do have an API, so maybe you can pull some info out. You can read the documentation to see what's possible.

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign is a cloud based service. The DocuSign eSignature API is only used with that context. It enables you to use the cloud service. If you wish to store documents etc. on your own servers, you cannot use the DocuSign agreement cloud.
There's a on-premise DocuSign Appliance, which you can explore, but this requires you to install, configure and maintain the entire DS appliance yourself. You can find information about the [DSA API on the Developer Center](https://developers.docusign.com/dsa-api).